# Issues with AA extension for chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, rpa, automationanywhere

I am trying to set up AA for use with chrome on a clients vm. AA client is up and running. 
When i first launched chrome everything was fine.
After i installed the AA chrome extension launching is not done correctly anymore: the url misses ":"
e.g "https://example.com" would become "https//example.com" resulting in connection errors.

Background/Additional Information:

aa extension:

1. was installed directly in browser in developer mode
2. unable to install it via the aa plugin settings for unknown reasons - also thankful for help on this problem
3. problem did NOT exist prior to extension installation
4. problem persists after extension removal
5. problem persists after un- and reinstallation of chrome

system:

1. vm with dedicated user-vmMachine-mapping
2. only intranet urls accessible

AA version 11.3.2

Any advise how to resolve this issue?

Thankful for any input.

Comment: For the URL missies part; do you mean when you run the URL using Automation Anywhere?

Comment: i mean: when the "launch website" command is executed the url is missing the ":" in the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** This issue has been addressed and fixed in version 11.3.2.1

**Solution:** Update to version 11.3.2.1, and your problem will be solved.

**Reference:** [Zendesk ticket ID 194226](https://docs.automationanywhere.com/bundle/enterprise-v11.3/page/topics/release-notes/release-notes-11-3-2-1.html)

> In the Launch Website command, URLs that have the www missing start properly in Internet Explorer. Also, http// is not automatically inserted after http:// when you run the automation.

Answer (score 0):

Note on a workaround we use, besides the answer of khaled:

We simply don't use the 'launch website' command with 'override default browser' set to chrome, but the 'open program/file' command with program path="chrome.exe" and 'parameter'=url.